# Regex to get a combination of constant and pattern

Tags: perl, pentaho, regex-negation, kettle, pdi

I am working on a regex which can help me in replacing a pattern in string.

The string that I have in stream is very long and after applying the regex(Find the pattern and then replace with constant value) I have to carry forward the string into my ETL stream.

```
To find:
<customer attribute="any number">
 like <customer attribute="1">
and replace with:
<customer>. (basically just keep "customer" and delete everything)
```

I am new to Regex and learning it.

Any help!!

Comment: `$str=~s/<customer[^>]*attribute="([^\"]*)"[^>]*>/<customer>/g;` Here attribute can be shuffled or more than one attribute will be possible hence we are using `[^>]*`.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like you're parsing `XML` with regular expressions. If so: It's a bad idea, use `XML::Twig` instead. (Post some XML and desired output, and I will give you an example of how to do it right)

Comment: @ssr1012 - Not working :(

Comment: Provide your input.

Comment: Input: <consumer attribute="1"><birth-date>1990-07-23</birth-date>
</consumer>  Output : <consumer><birth-date>1990-07-23</birth-date>
</consumer>. Can be any number(1 to 1000) as attribute's value.

Comment: `my $element_name = "consumer";
my $str = "<consumer attribute=\"1\"><birth-date>1990-07-23</birth-date> </consumer>";
$str=~s/<($element_name)[^>]*attribute="[^\"]*"[^>]*>/<$1>/g;
print $str; output:
<consumer><birth-date>1990-07-23</birth-date> </consumer>`

Comment: @ssr1012. Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: @vikas - please [edit] that into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Input:

`<consumer attribute=\"1\"><birth-date>1990-07-23</birth-date> </consumer>;`

```
my $element_name = "consumer";

my $str = "<consumer attribute=\"1\"><birth-date>1990-07-23</birth-date> </consumer>";

$str=~s/<($element_name)[^>]*attribute="[^\"]*"[^>]*>/<$1>/g;

print $str;
```

> output:

`<consumer><birth-date>1990-07-23</birth-date> </consumer>`

Comment: @DaveCross: Do you point out in any posting if did this. I am sure I didn't encouraged regex using XML conversions. I just forwarded the answer for queries in regex. Enough. Thanks for your downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Please, please, please. [Don't use regular expressions to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

It's bad news. It's brittle and hacky, and most importantly of all - completely unnecessary.

Regular expressions do not handle context. And XML is all about context.

`XML` already has a query language called `xpath` which is far better suited.

Here's an example of *finding* a node using `xpath`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ('yourfile.xml'); 

print $twig -> get_xpath('//consumer', 0) -> att('attribute'),"\n";
```

But if you want to transform it and delete `attribute`:

```
$_ -> del_att('attribute') for $twig -> get_xpath('//consumer[@attribute]');
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig -> print;
```

I would ask though - why are you trying to do that? It sounds rather like another broken process somewhere - maybe another script trying to `regex` the XML?

But the other thing that `XML::Twig` does *really* well is it has `twig_handlers` that let you handle XML streams more neatly (e.g. without needing to parse it all into memory.

That goes a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub delete_unwanted {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_; 
    $element -> del_att('attribute'); 
    #dump progress so far 'out'. 
    $twig -> flush; 
    #free memory already processed. 
    $twig -> purge; 
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { '//consumer[@attribute]' => \&delete_unwanted } );
   $twig -> parsefile ( 'your_xml.xml');
```

We set a handler, so that each time the parser encounters a `consumer` with an `attribute` attribute. (Bad name that) it deletes it, `flush`es (prints) the parsed XML, and purges it from memory. This makes it very memory efficient, as you're not reading the whole thing into memory, and can do pretty much inline regexing type operations.

Comment: The OP is talking about a stream. This would be a great place to advertise XML::Twig's ability to work with chunked data.

Comment: @Sobrique. First of all thanks a lot for your time. You elaborated the point so well. But in my case I am using Penatho Kettle to make my first draft of XML. Then a lot of manipulation is done and for traversing purpose I added "attribute". Finally I need to remove that.

Comment: Well, that sound like you may be tackling this problem in a less than ideal way. Most things you pass XML to, if the attribute is redundant... it'll be irrelevant. That's part of the point of XML.